# Mac OS X - switching between languages

Tags: mac, keyboard, language

I have got two languages, *Czech* and *English*.

I would like to switch to English language with combination of <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>

Is it possible to configure this on Mac?